# how to kill music service?

Tags: android, service

i'm making a simple Activity about killing running services.
i found a method "killBackgroundProcesses" to kill background app or servies.
i tried killing background apps and services.
running apps and some servies are killed well, but especially Music Service is never killed...

I want to make a simeple app which is killing background music service.
the app has just one button(name is "Kill Music")
If user clicks the button, the background music should be killed.

the music is played by default music player..
how can i kill the background music?
is there any other method to kill music service?

here is my code i tried..
any suggestion will be appreciate.
thank you.

```
public class Android32_TaskKillerActivity extends Activity {
ActivityManager manager;  
List<RunningServiceInfo> list;
String str="";  //to contain running Servies name and write on Toast message.

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  //to kill All Services
    manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    list = manager.getRunningServices(300);  //save current Servies to List

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                RunningServiceInfo info = list.get(i);
                String temp = info.service.getPackageName();
                     str += temp+"\n";
                manager.killBackgroundProcesses(temp);//killing services one by one to the end.

            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All Services are finished \n" + str, 3000).show();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: You're illustrating the reasons apps aren't allowed to do this sort of thing anymore. ;) You only want to kill music services but your code is using a list of **all** running services. Worse, it's passing through a stale list of running services that was populated when the activity was first created. Task killer apps have had a history of causing other apps to malfunction (including alarm clocks!) which leads to deeply frustrated users who have no easy way of knowing why. The ability for apps to disrupt the system this way has been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make a simeple app which is killing background music service. the app has just one button(name is "Kill Music") If user clicks the button, the background music should be killed.

This is not possible.

`killBackgroundProcesses()` will kill *background* processes. However, there are multiple definitions of the word "background" (and, conversely, "foreground"). The Music app has called `startForeground()` to indicate to Android that it is part of the foreground user experience and should not be shut down due to low memory conditions if possible.

Quoting the `killBackgroundProcesses()` documentation:

> This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed.

Hence, `killBackgroundProcesses()` should not be killing services that use `startForeground()`, such as the Music app.

The user can stop the Music app either through the Music app or, if they are a particularly strange user, via the Settings application.